# How do I specify a view to be pushed as Modal in MvvmCross?

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I have a view in a MonoTouch app using MvvmCross framework that I would like displayed Modal (NavigationController.PresentModalViewController).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MvvmCross starts from the premise that all ViewModels are just "normal pages" - so in iOS/MonoTouch that means UIViewControllers presented using a UINavigationController.

To move away from this premise - towards tabbed displays, modal displays, split controllers, popups, etc - then you can adjust the Presenter logic within your MonoTouch app.

The presenter's job is to implement:

```
public interface IMvxTouchViewPresenter
{
    void Show(MvxShowViewModelRequest view);
    void Close(IMvxViewModel viewModel);
    void CloseModalViewController();
    void ClearBackStack();
    bool PresentModalViewController(UIViewController controller, bool animated);
    void NativeModalViewControllerDisappearedOnItsOwn();
}
```

The presenter used for your app is selected in AppDelegate construction - e.g. see how the [TwitterSearch](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/master/Sample%20-%20TwitterSearch/TwitterSearch.UI.Touch/AppDelegate.cs) builds different presenters for iPhone and iPad.

---

Fortunately, for simple Modal support, one of the standard presenters available is [MvxModalSupportTouchViewPresenter.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/master/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/Touch/Views/Presenters/MvxModalSupportTouchViewPresenter.cs)

This presenter looks to see if the view being presented has the `IMvxModalTouchView` marker interface - it tests `view is IMvxModalTouchView`. If this interface is present, then it uses modal presentation for the view instead of "normal navigation".

To use this, change your AppDelegate code to something:

```
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

        // initialize app for single screen iPhone display
        var presenter = new MvxModalSupportTouchViewPresenter(this, window);
        var setup = new Setup(this, presenter);
        setup.Initialize();

        // start the app
        var start = this.GetService<IMvxStartNavigation>();
        start.Start();

        window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

        return true;
    }
```

Then add the marker interface to your modal View(s):

```
 public class MyView : MvxBindingTouchViewController<MyViewModel>, IMvxModalTouchView
 {
      // ....
 }
```

Comment: Nice one Stuart. Great framework by the way. This is underpinning a large project.

Comment: Cool - if you have small chat questions, come and find us on http://jabbr.net/#/rooms/mvvmcross - otherwise, using SO is perfect

Comment: Also, for any reasonable size iPhone/iPad app, I expect you are gong to end up writing your own presenter at some point - especially for iPad.