# Login Modal view not showing over a splitview using Xamarin iOS and MVVMCross

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I'm working on an iPad app using splitview controller and MVVMCross which requires a login screen. I'd like the login screen to appear as a modal popover in the centre of the screen, over the top of the underlying screen which is controlled by a UISplitViewController.Ideally I'd like the 'master' view to be hidden and then appear after a successful login. I understand my UISplitViewController has to be the root controller, so I need to launch the popover from either the master or detail view at an appropriate event

Answer (score 0):

**General iOS modal views:**

When doing modal views, I tend to do something like this inside the view that we want to be the parent of the modal view.

```
var myViewController = new UIViewController();
var myModalNavigation= new UINavigationController(myViewController)
{
    ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FormSheet,
    ModalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CoverVertical
}

this.PresentModalViewOnTop(myModalNavigation);
```

We create our view controller, then a navigation controller using the view controller. We give the nav controller a modal presentation and transition style. Then inside the view controller that will launch the modal view we call `this.PresentModalViewOnTop();`.

In your case in particular, you'd probably want to do this code from your "master view". But you can make it do that inside ViewDidLoad to ensure they can't use your "master view" until the modal has been satisfied and disappeared.

**Modal views in MvvmCross:**

You'll need to change your presenter logic as MvvmCross assumes every view model is just a normal full "page". There is a great explanation of how to do this here: [How do I specify a view to be pushed as Modal in MvvmCross?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512853/how-do-i-specify-a-view-to-be-pushed-as-modal-in-mvvmcross)

Comment: The above scenario works fine when i used only xamarin but when i try to integrate with mvvmcross then it not work as expected.